# Informix Query Where Clause

Tags: mysql, where-clause, informix

Help All,

I am writing a query in Informix and have been stuck on the where clause.  I have 2 CSQnames that I want to select and certain times and all others I want to show in between another time.  My query ran perfectly until I added this specific where statement.  If anyone can offer suggestions I would really appreciate it.  I am getting a general error.  In Informix since I am unable to put a if then statement in the where clause how would I rewrite my syntax?  Thanks!

```
SELECT
(ccd.nodeid||"-"||ccd.sessionid||"-"||ccd.sessionseqnum) as sequenceID,
ccd.sessionid as sessionid,
ccd.sessionseqnum as sequencenum,
ccd.applicationName as AppName,
csqname as CSQName, ccd.flowout, ccd.conference,

CASE WHEN contacttype=1 THEN "Incoming" 
                WHEN contacttype=2 THEN "Outgoing"
                WHEN contacttype=3 THEN "In House"
                WHEN contacttype=4 THEN "Redirect In"
                WHEN contacttype=5 THEN "Transfer In"
END as ContactType,
CASE WHEN contactdisposition = 1 THEN "Abandoned" 
                WHEN contactdisposition = 2 THEN "Handled" 
                WHEN contactdisposition = 4 THEN "Aborted"
                WHEN contactdisposition >= 5 THEN "Rejected"
END as ContactDisposition,
CASE WHEN originatortype=1 THEN "Agent" 
                WHEN originatortype=2 THEN "Device"
                ELSE "Unknown"
END as OriginatorType,
CASE WHEN destinationtype=1 THEN "Agent" 
                WHEN destinationtype=2 THEN "Device"
                ELSE "Unknown"
END as DestinationType,
DATE(ccd.startdatetime) as date,
ccd.startdatetime as starttime,
ccd.enddatetime as endtime,
res.resourcename, ccd.transfer, ccd.redirect,
ccd.originatordn, ccd.destinationdn, 
crd.queuetime/86400 as queuetime,
acd.talktime/86400 as TalkTime, 
acd.holdtime/86400 as HoldTime, 
acd.worktime/86400 as WorkTime
FROM contactcalldetail ccd
                 Left JOIN contactroutingdetail crd ON crd.sessionID = ccd.sessionID
                 AND crd.sessionSeqNum = ccd.sessionSeqNum 
                 AND crd.nodeID = ccd.nodeID 
                 AND crd.profileID = ccd.profileID
                 LEFT JOIN agentconnectiondetail acd ON acd.sessionID = ccd.sessionID
                 AND acd.sessionSeqNum = ccd.sessionSeqNum 
                 AND acd.nodeID = ccd.nodeID 
                 AND acd.profileID = ccd.profileID
                LEFT JOIN resource res ON acd.resourceid = res.resourceid
left join contactqueuedetail cqd on cqd.sessionid=crd.sessionid
left join contactservicequeue csq on  cqd.targetid= csq.recordid

WHERE (
                ccd.startdatetime BETWEEN '2014-1-2 13:00:00' AND '2016-12-31 22:30:00'

      AND (
         if (csqname in ("CSQ_Emeriti" , "SOS-Emeriti") 

AND EXTEND(ccd.startdatetime, HOUR TO second) > DATETIME(13:30:00) HOUR TO SECOND
                 AND EXTEND(ccd.startdatetime, HOUR TO second) < DATETIME(22:00:00) HOUR TO SECOND
                                                    ) 
             or(csqname not in (“CSQ_Emeriti" , "SOS-Emeriti") 
AND 
               EXTEND(ccd.startdatetime, HOUR TO second) > DATETIME(13:00:00) HOUR TO SECOND

AND EXTEND(ccd.startdatetime, HOUR TO second) < DATETIME(22:30:00) HOUR TO SECOND
                                    )
                    )
                    AND WEEKDAY(ccd.startdatetime) BETWEEN 1 AND 5
                    AND (contacttype IN (1,4,5))
                    AND ccd.originatordn !='2155870700'
    )
```

Comment: exactly HOW is this not working for you?

Comment: I am getting a general error (that's what it says).  My code runs when I remove the if or statements and just have one logical clause.

Comment: Please make the indents smaller so the code can actually be read without having to scroll a lot.

Comment: This is my code when it runs fine.  I just need to add in an if else statement for the times and csqnames.WHERE (ccd.startdatetime BETWEEN '2014-1-2 13:00:00' AND '2016-12-31 22:30:00'
AND EXTEND(ccd.startdatetime, HOUR TO second) > DATETIME(13:00:00) HOUR TO SECOND
AND EXTEND(ccd.startdatetime, HOUR TO second) < DATETIME(22:30:00) HOUR TO SECOND
AND WEEKDAY(ccd.startdatetime) BETWEEN 1 AND 5
AND (contacttype IN (1,4,5))
AND ccd.originatordn !='2155870700')

Answer (score 1):

If the query is on **Informix**, `if` is not available in the `WHERE` clause of **SQL Statement**.

If I understood you correctly what you want is:

```
...
AND (
        (   
            csqname in ("CSQ_Emeriti" , "SOS-Emeriti") 
            AND EXTEND(ccd.startdatetime, HOUR TO second) > DATETIME(13:30:00) HOUR TO SECOND
            AND EXTEND(ccd.startdatetime, HOUR TO second) < DATETIME(22:00:00) HOUR TO SECOND
         ) 
    OR
        (
            csqname not in ("CSQ_Emeriti" , "SOS-Emeriti") 
            AND EXTEND(ccd.startdatetime, HOUR TO second) > DATETIME(13:00:00) HOUR TO SECOND
            AND EXTEND(ccd.startdatetime, HOUR TO second) < DATETIME(22:30:00) HOUR TO SECOND
        )
)
...
```

Keen regards.